# Is it possible to know expected member type of array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to know expected type of a typed array:

```
let A1:string[] = [],
    A2:Date[] = [],
    expectedType = (arr:any[]) => {
       console.log("Expecting: " + /*some magic*/);
    };

expectedType(A1); // prints string
expectedType(A2); // prints Date
```

**UPD:**
As it's stated in the answer,currently there is no possibility to know Array memebers decalder type in TS, however you can do something like:

```
    class StrictArray extends Array {
        private _expectedType: {new(): T}; // constructor type definition
        get expectedType():{new(): T} {return this._expectedType;};
        constructor(ctype: {new(): T}, args?:any) {
             super.constructor(args);
        }

//...
        push(t:any) {
            if (!(t.constructor !== this._expectedType))
                throw "Not valid type";
            return super.push(t);
        }
    }
```

Now we have objects that behave like a normal arrays, but we'll be able to retrieve and control their members type.

So our example will be:

```
let A1:StrictArray = new StrictArray(string),
    A2:StrictArray = new StrictArray(Date);

    /*magic = */
    A1.expectedType.name; // prints string
    A2.expectedType.name; // prints Date
```

Not sure about how this can be usefull or harmfull, please leave a comments.

Comment: No. TypeScript types are not manifest at runtime and are fully erased from the output code. You can do minimal checking but it is solely using JavaScript's facilities and is mostly orthogonal to compile time checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to know expected member type of array in typescript?

No. Type information is removed before compiling to JS so you get what you have with JS. You can do JS style introspection e.g. `typeof arr[0] === 'string'` but JavaScript is fairly limited.